# IHttpAsyncHandler flush - worker thread vs io thread

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool, worker-thread, ihttpasynchandler

I'm using `IHttpAsyncHandler` with `BeginProcessRequest` and `EndProcessRequest` methods.
Say I have the following code under `EndProcessRequest` method:

```
    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
         result.Context.Response.Write("Some message");
    }
```

The `Write` method itself only writes to an inner buffer, but when the `EndProcessRequest` is finished, the buffer is flushed to the stream and close the connection.

My question is which thread is doing the flush? the worker thread which ran the `EndProcessRequest` code or an IO thread?

Comment: You should probably structure your program so that it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is partly correct :) But say I have my current implementation with this IHttpAsyncHandler and I want to be sure that I'm optimized in the manner of the running time of my worker thread - which means that the flush operation should be done only by the IO thread - so that the worker thread won't need to wait for the IO thread to complete - how can I achieve that?

Comment: @TomerPeled I see now what you are looking for - I don't know and my answer does not really apply to mapping between [native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) an manged threadpools/threading in IIS. Deleted the answer as I believe I totally misunderstood the question: "I don't want that the flush operation will consume a worker thread time."